# How do I exclude the first column in my array?

Tags: python, arrays, mean

I'm trying to plot a graph of the mean time period against the load. The first column in my array is the load, and I want to exclude it from my mean calculation.

```
[[0.2  0.96 0.94 0.91 0.69  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [0.3  1.15 1.09 1.19 1.19 1.31 0.97 0.97  nan  nan  nan]
 [0.4  1.29 1.28 1.31 1.21  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [0.5  1.54 1.43 1.45 1.37 1.35 1.29  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [0.75 1.68 1.53 1.68 1.75 1.8  1.78  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [1.   1.93 2.04 1.91 1.94  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

```
#define the function
def clean_array(data):
    """Return a shortened array with any nans removed"""
    return data[np.logical_not(np.isnan(data))]
```

```
clean_array(data[0]).mean(), clean_array(data[0]).std(ddof=1)
```

```
(0.74, 0.32070235421649157)
```

Comment: What kind of load? E.g., does it have a (physical) unit?

Answer (score 0):

Simply slice the array, save it a new and then apply *mean()* on it.

```
np.array(data)[:,1:]
```

Comment: I've split my data but how do I actually change my code to calculate the mean?

Comment: Erin, what are you trying to calculate the mean of? every single item in the list that is not the first entry?